# I want to know value intersections between binary image and circle

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, ear, biometrics

[image: 004_1.bmp]

```
clc
clear
a = imread('004_1.bmp');
I2 = imcrop(a,[80 17 101 180]);
[i,j]=size(I2);    


x_hist=sum(I2,1);
y_hist=(sum(I2,2))';

x=1:j ; y=1:i;
centx=sum(x.*x_hist)/sum(x_hist)
centy=sum(y.*y_hist)/sum(y_hist)


BW = edge(I2,'Canny',0.329);
bw2 = imcomplement(BW);
circle = int32([centx,centy,40]);
shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('Fill',false);
release(shapeInserter);
set(shapeInserter,'Shape','Circles');
K = step(shapeInserter,bw2,circle);


figure, imshow(K)
```

I have this program and I want to know value from the intersection between circle and binary image. If anyone know how to find the value?

Comment: YOu have to add the image too...so that users can try your code..

Comment: pic added..thank you for ur advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to obtain the indexes of the desired images as follows:

```
bwCircle = step(shapeInserter,true(size(bw2)),circle); % construct binary image of circle only
[i, j] = find ((bw2 | bwCircle) == 0); % find the indexes of the intersection between the binary image and the circle

figure 
imshow(bw2 & bwCircle) % plot the combination of both images
hold on
plot(j, i, 'r*') % plot the intersection points
```

[image]

Comment: if i want to sum all intersection, how can i sum it?but i want to sum all intersection by clockwise

Comment: It may be a good idea to ask a separate question about it. If you sum them all, why do you want to take it clockwise?

Comment: oh i'm sorry before. i mean i want sum all intersection point by clockwise direction to get one value. thats what i thought